# JQuery Return class name based on partial string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a few divs with class name denoting steps:

```
<div class="steps jsStep1 circle">Step 1</div>
<div class="steps jsStep2 circle">Step 2</div>
<div class="steps jsStep3 circle">Step 3</div>
```

My js is wired up like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".steps", function () {
     var selectedStep = $(this).attr('class').match('["jsStep"]')
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is get full class name eg "jsStep3" if that div was clicked. What I am getting is ["s"].
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Use data for data, ie `<div class='steps' data-step='jsStep1' ..>` then `$(this).data("step")`

Comment: Thanx for this alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you have getting `["s"]` because the string `'["jsStep"]'` would get converted to regex [`/["jsStep"]/`](https://regex101.com/r/xleGUk/1) and the first match would be `s` in all case.

---

To make it work provide a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object as an argument of [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".steps", function() {
  var selectedStep = $(this).attr('class').match(/jsStep\d+/)[0];
  console.log(selectedStep);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="steps jsStep1 circle">Step 1</div>
<div class="steps jsStep2 circle">Step 2</div>
<div class="steps jsStep3 circle">Step 3</div>
```

---

But a better way would be using custom `data-*` attribute which can easily get by using [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".steps", function() {
  var selectedStep = $(this).data('step');
  console.log(selectedStep);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-step="jsStep1" class="steps circle">Step 1</div>
<div data-step="jsStep2" class="steps circle">Step 2</div>
<div data-step="jsStep3" class="steps circle">Step 3</div>
```